# INTERNAL exception while reading document from Firestore in Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, promise, google-cloud-functions

I am using Flutter to develop my app with Firebase as my backend and using cloud functions to get images into the app. I have stored all of the image urls in cloud Firestore so I wrote a function to get those images, but while applying it from the app, I am getting this error.

> PlatformException(functionsError, Cloud function failed with exception., {code: INTERNAL, details: null, message: INTERNAL})

**index.js**

```
exports.getDownloadUrl = functions.region("asia-south1").https.onCall((data, context) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var colors = {};

        var db = admin.firestore();
        db.collection('feed')
          .document("pets")
          .collection("cats")
          .get()
          .then(snapshot => {
              snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                  var key = doc.id;
                  var color = doc.data();
                  color['url'] = key;

                  colors[key] = color;
              });

              var colorsStr = JSON.stringify(colors, null, '\t');
              console.log('colors callback result : ' + colorsStr);
              colors = color;

              resolve(colors);
              return colors;
          }).catch(reason => {
              console.log('db.collection("colors").get gets err, reason: ' + reason);
              reject(reason);
          });
          return colors;
    });

});
```

**flutter.dart**

```
void cloudFunc() async {
    final CloudFunctions cf = CloudFunctions(
      app: Firebase.app(),
      region: 'asia-south1'
    );
    final HttpsCallable urlHttpsCallable = cf.getHttpsCallable(
      functionName: 'downloadUrl',
    );
    final HttpsCallableResult urlHttpsCallableResult = await urlHttpsCallable.call();
    print("url: " + urlHttpsCallableResult.data.toString());
  }
```

**NOTE:** There is nothing wrong with the flutter code, or the instantiation of the `CloudFunction`, because I have tried a test `helloWorld` function before with the same flutter code **AND** this js code deploys perfectly without any error.

**UPDATE:** As per @DougStevenson's advice, here is one of the logs from the console

> Error detected in getDownloadUrl  > {"errorGroup":"CJTI4Nv74rfinQE","errorEvent":{"message":"Unhandled error TypeError: db.collection(...).document is not a function\n    at Promise (/workspace/index.js:39:12)\n    at new Promise ()\n    at exports.getDownloadUrl.functions.region.https.onCall (/workspace/index.js:33:12)\n    at func (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:273:32)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)","eventTime":"2020-09-19T12:34:11.358Z","serviceContext":{"resourceType":"cloud_function","service":"getDownloadUrl"}},"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.devtools.clouderrorreporting.v1beta1.Insight"}

Comment: Look in the Functions console log for errors to see what went wrong.  There's not enough information here to know what happened or how to fix it, so please update the question with the specific error message generated by the function code.

Comment: In a sea of small nonsenses, `colors = color;` stands out because `colour` is not in scope. Even if it was, the assignment would make no sense.

Comment: I didn't quite understand, do you mind being elaborate?

Comment: 'color' is local to the `.forEach()` functor.

Comment: Okay yeah got it, but is that the only mistake in this piece of code?

Comment: The `new Promise()` wrpper is unnecessary. Simply `return db.collection(...).doc(...).collection(...).get().then(...);`

Comment: okay, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the Firestore API for JavaScript correctly.  The error message is telling you what's wrong:

> Unhandled error TypeError: db.collection(...).document is not a function

In JavaScript, it's `doc()`, not `document()`.